# iOS crash when I resume app: "applicationDidBecomeActive:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, swift

I have an observer that checks when the application becomes active and calls `applicationDidBecomeActive`. When I remove that code, there isn't any crash, but I need that code.

I call `addActiveObserver` in `ViewDidAppear` and `removeActiveObserver` in `ViewDidDisappear`, but when I set breakpoints on each, only `ViewDidAppear` ever gets hit.

When I tap the home button and then the app again, I get the following crash:

`applicationDidBecomeActive:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

`viewDidAppear` / `viewDidDisappear`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    addActiveObserver()
}
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    removeActiveObserver()
}
```

`addActiveObserver` / `removeActiveObserver`

```
func addActiveObserver() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(UIApplicationDelegate.applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
        object: nil)
}
func removeActiveObserver() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
                                      name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
                                      object:nil)
}
```

`applicationDidBecomeActive`:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification) {
    // Do work
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `UIApplicationDelegate` part in your selector, because that refers to a function **in the general delegate of the application** and not in the custom class that you are having. You should remove it.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)),
    name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
    object: nil)
```